# LINQ query to select top five

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query:

```
var list = from t in ctn.Items
           where t.DeliverySelection == true && t.Delivery.SentForDelivery == null
           orderby t.Delivery.SubmissionDate
           select t;
```

How can I modify this query to select just five results from the database?

Comment: Take(how_many_you_wish)

Comment: If you want efficiency use SQL and Dapper 

Answer (score 505, accepted):

```
var list = (from t in ctn.Items
           where t.DeliverySelection == true && t.Delivery.SentForDelivery == null
           orderby t.Delivery.SubmissionDate
           select t).Take(5);
```

Comment: +1, but gah, wrapping multiline expressions in parentheses and then de-referencing the whole lot really grates me for some reason.

Comment: This seems to take as many results from the database as match the equality conditions, and only after they are taken from the database does it apply the take(5) restriction within the application. Is there a way to literally `take` only the first 5 rows from the database?

Comment: @JMHicks not really. The Take(5) command is only adding yet another condition to the IQueryable, which will not execute until you enumerate it. However, there may be LINQ providers that doesn't support the Take operation.

Comment: @JMHicks -- that is not the way linq works... linq is lazy.

Comment: How to Rewrite this as LINQ to object?

Comment: @HosseinSedghian , I assume you mean the Lambda expression way of writing it:
`ctn.Items.Where(t=> t.DeliverySelection == true && t.Delivery.SentForDelivery == null).OrderBy(t => t.Delivery.SubmissionDate).Take(5)`

Comment: Does this handle the case where it is specified to take more rows than are available?

Comment: @KevinBurton , yes. In SQL `SELECT TOP (5)` would also not fail if only 3 rows exist.

Comment: @JMHicks According to the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-6.0 this construction will NOT enumerate the whole set first. Quote: `Take` is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach

Answer (score 45):

The solution:

```
var list = (from t in ctn.Items
           where t.DeliverySelection == true && t.Delivery.SentForDelivery == null
           orderby t.Delivery.SubmissionDate
           select t).Take(5);
```

Answer (score 28):

This can also be achieved using the [lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function)-based approach of LINQ;

```
var list = ctn.Items
             .Where(t => t.DeliverySelection == true &&
                    t.Delivery.SentForDelivery == null)
             .OrderBy(t => t.Delivery.SubmissionDate)
             .Take(5);
```

Answer (score 12):

This can also be achieved using LINQ [fluent syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linq/info):

```
var list = ctn.Items
    .Where(t=> t.DeliverySelection == true && t.Delivery.SentForDelivery == null)
    .OrderBy(t => t.Delivery.SubmissionDate)
    .Take(5);
```

Note that each method (`Where`, `OrderBy`, [`Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) that appears in this LINQ statement takes a [lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lambda/info) as an argument. Also note that the documentation for `Enumerable.Take` begins with:

> Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a
> sequence.

<sub>*(This is offering a somewhat more descriptive answer than [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25988878/1497596) provided by [Ajni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3996928/anji).)*</sub>

Answer (score 8):

**`Additional information`**

Sometimes it is necessary to bind a model into a view models and give a **type conversion error**. In this situation you should use `ToList()` method.

```
var list = (from t in ctn.Items
       where t.DeliverySelection == true && t.Delivery.SentForDelivery == null
       orderby t.Delivery.SubmissionDate
       select t).Take(5).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I am just thinking you might be feel unfamiliar with the sequence From->Where->Select, as in an SQL script, it is like **Select->From->Where.**

But you may not know that inside the SQL engine, it is also parsing in the sequence of
'**From->Where->Select**'. To validate it, you can try a simple script,

```
select id as i from table where i=3
```

and it will not work. The reason is the engine will parse **Where** before **Select**, so it won't know alias `i` in the **where**.  To make this work, you can try

```
select * from (select id as i from table) as t where i = 3
```