# Get top 5 values with lambda query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

Here is my code,

```
rptAnnouncement.DataSource = DbContext.Announcements
    .Where(n => n.Expire_Date.Value.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date)
    .ToList();
```

I take the announcements data from database with lambda and bind this data to ASP.NET repeater(`rptAnnouncement`).

But this query returns all of the data, I just want to get the top 5 (first 5) records like MS SQL Server's `select top 5 * from database`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ query to select top five](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872946/linq-query-to-select-top-five)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use [`OrderBy()`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx&ei=hppWUeSXEurtiAfesYGACw&usg=AFQjCNHL40DuYXlcH-pcgqSuSsQ9bPJnaA&bvm=bv.44442042,d.aGc) to order the elements and then [`Take()`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx&ei=h5pWUbC4LuOsiAfLzIHACg&usg=AFQjCNHdOrPitywW78nbI8GqqpQjuj3KMQ&bvm=bv.44442042,d.aGc) to take the first 5.

```
rptAnnouncement.DataSource = DbContext.Announcements
    .Where(n => n.Expire_Date.Value.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date)
    .OrderBy(n => n.Expire_Date.Value.Date)
    .Take(5);
```

**Notes**

- You can order descending by using [`OrderByDescending()`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx&ei=RZ1WUfeICuW8iAe074HYDw&usg=AFQjCNFuVGwTTxwuau5LqvCuuxXz8_ldNg&bvm=bv.44442042,d.aGc)
- Calling [`ToList()`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx&ei=ep1WUefGBauRiQe954CoDQ&usg=AFQjCNHvmnwCkNpg48rE0FN7xBPuGnYDFg&bvm=bv.44442042,d.aGc) and then calling [`Take()`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx&ei=e51WUb7UH4muiQfvwIDIBA&usg=AFQjCNHdOrPitywW78nbI8GqqpQjuj3KMQ&bvm=bv.44442042,d.aGc) will get all of the items and then take the top 5 as opposed to only getting the top 5.

Comment: Thanks , i do forget to order by date :D

Comment: ha ha :D . by the way Daniel , how can i set (ascending , descending ) to order !

Answer (score 5):

If you only want the Top 5 then you can use the below .

```
rptAnnouncement.DataSource = DbContext.Announcements.Where(n => n.Expire_Date.Value.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date).Take(5).ToList();
```

More details here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Take(n)` in `LINQ`

```
rptAnnouncement.DataSource = DbContext.Announcements
                                      .Where(n => n.Expire_Date.Value.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date)
                                      .Take(5).ToList();
```

Comment: It should be .Take(5).ToList(), not the opposite.