# Query a list and select top 10 values

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq

I have a list of objects in which each object has a property called "Frequency" and I want to be able to pick the top 10 objects that have the highest frequencies.

I saw some solutions that are kind of similar to what I am looking to solve using LINQ so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use OrderBy (either ascending or descending) and then Take(10).

Comment: `var youwant=list.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Frequency).Take(10);`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow kristof. I would suggest you to check the help center because it would help you to avoid asking questions already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872946/linq-query-to-select-top-five?s=1|101.2250 and make question of better quality, providing a [mcve] which could have better answers.

Comment: @Reniuz please do note it is a new contributor, the "we expect here some effort" is a bit rude.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can order the list by descending Frequency and then take the first 10 like this:

```
var top10 = objectList.OrderByDescending(o => o.Frequency).Take(10);
```